# What is this C++ code attempting to achieve?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm studying the DTMF code at http://sourceforge.net/projects/dtmf/.  I've come across some C++ code that I'm having trouble understanding:

```
template<int, int, int, int> class Types;
template <> class Types<5, 4, 2, 1>
{
public:
        typedef long int Int40;
        typedef unsigned long int Uint40;
        typedef int Int32;
        typedef unsigned int Uint32;
        typedef short int Int16;
        typedef unsigned short int Uint16;
        typedef char Int8;
        typedef unsigned char Uint8;
};
template <> class Types<8, 4, 2, 1>
{
public:
        typedef long int Int64;
        typedef unsigned long int Uint64;
        typedef int Int32;
        typedef unsigned int Uint32;
        typedef short int Int16;
        typedef unsigned short int Uint16;
        typedef char Int8;
        typedef unsigned char Uint8;
};
template <> class Types<4, 4, 2, 1>
{
public:
        typedef int Int32;
        typedef unsigned int Uint32;
        typedef short int Int16;
        typedef unsigned short int Uint16;
        typedef char Int8;
        typedef unsigned char Uint8;
};

// For 16bit chars
template <> class Types<2, 1, 1, 1>
{
public:
        typedef long int Int32;
        typedef unsigned long int Uint32;
        typedef short int Int16;
        typedef unsigned short int Uint16;
};

typedef Types<sizeof(long int), sizeof(int), sizeof(short int), sizeof(char)>::Int32     INT32;
typedef Types<sizeof(long int), sizeof(int), sizeof(short int), sizeof(char)>::Uint32    UINT32;
typedef Types<sizeof(long int), sizeof(int), sizeof(short int), sizeof(char)>::Int16     INT16;
typedef Types<sizeof(long int), sizeof(int), sizeof(short int), sizeof(char)>::Uint16    UINT16;
```

From there, they are used just like normal primitive types:

```
static const INT16 tempCoeff[8];
```

My gut feeling tells me that all this stuff achieves some sort of cross-platform portability.  Am I right, or is there more to it?

Comment: Yep, standardizing byte-sizes across platforms

Comment: It looks like he's handling different architectural models in a particularly convoluted way, e.g. 8, 4, 2, 1 is 8 byte long, 4 byte int, 2 byte short and 1 byte char. I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use `<stdint.h>` ?

Comment: @Paul R I have a strange recollection that MS compilers don't provide `stdint.h`.

Comment: Five-byte `long`? I wonder what machine that is.

Comment: @Rob: probably a DSP (TI I would guess)

Comment: @Mark B: you're right - MS still doesn't even support C99. My preferred solution is to use the normal `<stdint.h>` on all "proper" platforms and then provide a custom `"stdint.h"` for MS platforms.

Comment: I do not understand why bother to define `Types<...>::Int40` or `Types<...>::Int64` if they cannot be used on certain platforms. Predictably there is no namespace level version because it would cause a compiler error, and nobody is going to type `Types<...>::Int64` to get it when necessary... Anyone got a clue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like they're reinventing `stdint.h` (which I believe isn't supported in some/many versions of MS compilers) by providing a somewhat portable mechanism for integral types of certain sizes based on calls to `sizeof`. Note that the fourth template parameter that accepts `sizeof(char)` is completely useless as `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft does not care about C and never implemented C99 and C++ only adopted stdint in C++11 which Microsoft is last to implement (Clang has support almost complete, gcc closely follows, VisualC++ has maybe half of features).

Comment: Plus there are many systems that simply have ancient compilers. Various embedded systems often get compiler update once in many years.

Comment: +1 for `sizeof(char)`. Always get me worried when someone wishes to provide a "framework" and trips on the fundamentals... (and the fact that a signed type is used for the result of `sizeof` is not particularly tasteful either).

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can devise a little bit more sane approach (requires that `CHAR_BIT` is correctly defined for the platform):

```
namespace portable_inttypes
{
    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize = sizeof (T) * CHAR_BIT, bool atleast64 = Tsize >= 64>
    struct autodef_helper64 : Tchain {};

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize>
    struct autodef_helper64<Tchain, T, Tun, Tsize, true> : Tchain
    {
        typedef T int_least64_t;
        typedef Tun uint_least64_t;
    };

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun>
    struct autodef_helper64<Tchain, T, Tun, 64, true> : Tchain
    {
        typedef T int64_t, int_least64_t;
        typedef Tun uint64_t, uint_least64_t;
    };

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize = sizeof (T) * CHAR_BIT, bool atleast32 = Tsize >= 32>
    struct autodef_helper32 : autodef_helper64<Tchain, T, Tun> {};

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize>
    struct autodef_helper32<Tchain, T, Tun, Tsize, true> : autodef_helper64<Tchain, T, Tun>
    {
        typedef T int_least32_t;
        typedef Tun uint_least32_t;
    };

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun>
    struct autodef_helper32<Tchain, T, Tun, 32, true> : autodef_helper64<Tchain, T, Tun>
    {
        typedef T int32_t, int_least32_t;
        typedef Tun uint32_t, uint_least32_t;
    };

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize = sizeof (T) * CHAR_BIT, bool atleast32 = Tsize >= 16>
    struct autodef_helper16 : autodef_helper32<Tchain, T, Tun> {};

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize>
    struct autodef_helper16<Tchain, T, Tun, Tsize, true> : autodef_helper32<Tchain, T, Tun>
    {
        typedef T int_least16_t;
        typedef Tun uint_least16_t;
    };

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun>
    struct autodef_helper16<Tchain, T, Tun, 16, true> : autodef_helper32<Tchain, T, Tun>
    {
        typedef T int16_t, int_least16_t;
        typedef Tun uint16_t, uint_least16_t;
    };

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize = sizeof (T) * CHAR_BIT, bool atleast8 = Tsize >= 8>
    struct autodef_helper8 : autodef_helper16<Tchain, T, Tun> {};

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun, size_t Tsize>
    struct autodef_helper8<Tchain, T, Tun, Tsize, true> : autodef_helper16<Tchain, T, Tun>
    {
        typedef T int_least8_t;
        typedef Tun uint_least8_t;
    };

    template<typename Tchain, typename T, typename Tun>
    struct autodef_helper8<Tchain, T, Tun, 8, true> : autodef_helper16<Tchain, T, Tun>
    {
        typedef T int8_t, int_least8_t;
        typedef Tun uint8_t, uint_least8_t;
    };

    struct autodef_base {};
    typedef autodef_helper8<autodef_base, long long, unsigned long long> autodef_longlong;
    typedef autodef_helper8<autodef_longlong, long, unsigned long> autodef_long;
    typedef autodef_helper8<autodef_long, int, unsigned> autodef_int;
    typedef autodef_helper8<autodef_int, short, unsigned short> autodef_short;
    typedef autodef_helper8<autodef_short, signed char, unsigned char> autodef_char;
}

typedef portable_inttypes::autodef_char inttypes;

int main(void)
{
    return sizeof(inttypes::uint32_t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works out the sizes of the different basic scalar types, and defines a few types depending on it.

So yes, it is used for cross-platform compatibility. Why it is used *that way*, though, is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This is usually done with a bunch of macros (that's what `stdint.h` does). The issue with this code is that it handles *four specific types of architectures*, and pathetically breaks if the sizes don't match one of the patterns.

Comment: Glad to hear that it's not the standard way to handle such a problem.  I was thinking about macros as well.

Comment: @misha: The standard is rather new. Microsoft never bothered to implement C99 that introduced this and C++11 is brand new; you still need to support C++03 based on C89 in many cases and than this is a good way to go.

Comment: @misha: See my answer (not tested) for a way to automatically define the size-specific types based on the platform.